# poetry install fails on macOS 11.6/Xcode 13: dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Python3

Tags: python, macos, python-poetry

New poetry install fails on macOS 11.6/Xcode 13, using official installer:

```
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
Retrieving Poetry metadata

# Welcome to Poetry!

This will download and install the latest version of Poetry,
a dependency and package manager for Python.

It will add the `poetry` command to Poetry's bin directory, located at:

/Users/u/Library/Python/3.8/bin

You can uninstall at any time by executing this script with the --uninstall option,
and these changes will be reverted.

Installing Poetry (1.1.12): An error occurred. Removing partial environment.
Poetry installation failed.
See /Users/u/poetry-installer-error-h3v75uw9.log for error logs.
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % more /Users/u/poetry-installer-error-h3v75uw9.log
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Python3
  Referenced from: /Users/u/Library/Application Support/pypoetry/venv/bin/python3
  Reason: image not found

Traceback:

  File "<stdin>", line 877, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 514, in run
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

There is no previous poetry install or reference to poetry in caches or Application Support:

```
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -al Library/Application\ Support/pypoetry
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 u  staff    64 26 Jan 16:58 .
drwx------+ 55 u  staff  1760 26 Jan 16:43 ..
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % ls -al Library/Caches/pypoetry
ls: Library/Caches/pypoetry: No such file or directory
```

Python version 3.8.9:

```
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Xcode version:

```
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ % xcodebuild -version
Xcode 13.2.1
Build version 13C100
u@s-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked through this by installing a non-system version of python3, then installing poetry.

1. `brew install pyenv`
2. `pyenv install 3.8.12`
3. `pyenv local 3.8.12`
4. `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -`

Comment: Might need the shell config as well (`pyenv init`) to get poetry to spot the installation.

Comment: I had to reload my shell after these steps but thank you!

Comment: I had to run: `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` as well.

Answer (score 2):

in my case (Apple M1, macOS 12.4) I overcame the issue and installed poetry successfully using the next command

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python3 -
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution, but it uses the deprecated installer, which cannot use the `self update` command to upgrade to 1.2.0a1 or later.